# Find a word with letters in wrong sequence using JS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string, find, match

How can i find a word that doesn't match with the searchcriteria, however has some equal letters in it?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/V6357/0/) to play a bit around.

If, the user types in `au` The first 2nd entries are displayed. But how can I achieve that the same thing happens when the user types in `ua`?

**JS**

I use the following to search for the `value` from an `input` and check if it exists in a list:

```
$("#search").on("keyup click", function () {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();

  $("#list").children().each(function () {
    var text = this.innerText.toLowerCase();
    $(this)[text.indexOf(value) !== 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" id="search">

<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#/australia/">Australia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/austria/">Austria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/belgium/">Belgium</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/brazil/">Brazil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/canada/">Canada</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/denmark/">Denmark</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/finland/">Finland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/france/">France</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/germany/">Germany</a></li>
    ...and so on...
</ul>
```

I'm not really familiar with `RegExp`, but i think that this will do the trick may?!

Comment: So you're basically looking for all combinations of characters entered, is that right? If I input "def" would it look for options starting with either: "def", "dfe", "efd", "edf", "fde", "fed" ?

Comment: @inhan Yeah, correct! That's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: If you wanted a very complete solution, you could use one of a couple great JS fuzzy-search implementations. Here are two that might be of use: [List.js](http://jonnystromberg.com/listjs-fuzzy-search-plugin) and [Fuse.js](http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html). I might recommend one of these if your project is more complex, as modeling data in JS data structures as opposed to the DOM will probably make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: @Cecchi Yeah, they are nice, but a bit too bloated for my intention ;)

Comment: Fair, but you should define "bloated". The overhead of loading a small file once asynchronously (Fuse.js is 1.58kb minified) might very well be a good tradeoff vs. relying entirely on DOM manipulation methods. Especially when the "fuzzy" results from one of these libraries might be more useful than the results provided by your spec. I'd argue it's worth testing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with RegExp, however you can use the following function to meet your needs:

```
function looseCharacterMatch(a, b) {
  a = a.split("");
  b = b.substring(0,a.length);
  var c = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b.replace(a[i], "") == b) {
      c = false;
    }
    b = b.replace(a[i], "");
  }
  return c;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V6357/2/show) | [Demo Source](http://jsfiddle.net/V6357/2/)

Answer (score 3):

I just made up this function. It returns true if `text` contains the sub-string `value`; even if the letters are scrambled **:

```
function fuzzyContains(text, value) {
    // for value = "THE", build the regex /[the]{3}/ and test
    var valueCopy = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, "");
    var regexp = new RegExp("[" + valueCopy + "]{" + valueCopy.length + "}");
    return regexp.test(text.toLowerCase());
}
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Nethe") // true
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Neteh") // true
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Nethl") // false
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/V6357/4/)

**Update**

Here is a revised version of the function. It returns true if `text` contains all characters from `value` **:

```
function fuzzyContains_v2(text, value) {
    var textCopy = text.toLowerCase();
    var valueCopy = value.toLowerCase().split("");
    console.log(textCopy, valueCopy);
    var a = $.grep(valueCopy, function (value) {
        return textCopy.indexOf(value) == -1;
    });
    return a.length == 0;
}
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Nethe")    // true
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Neteh")    // true
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Nethl")    // true
fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "Netlands") // true
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/V6357/5/)

** I have not tested the behavior when `value` contains repeated characters. However I am sure the results would still be acceptable.

Comment: I like that! Is it possible to let `fuzzyContains("Netherlands", "thl")` be `true`?

Comment: Yes but it would produce weird results more often.

Comment: @yckart To do what you want, change `{"+valueCopy.length+"}` to `{3,"+valueCopy.length+"}` (i.e. 3 or more of the set of letters in a row. Note that this solution will also mean that `fuzzyContains('Netherlands','NNNNNN')` will be true.

Comment: @yckart: see revised answer.

Comment: Nice, I'm happy for now! :-*

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var text = this.innerText.toLowerCase();

text = text.replace(/([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)/, '$2$1');
```

Comment: Can you explain your thoughts with this `regex` a bit?

Comment: This will just reverse the input, not what you need... :)